# Xcode 4 shows no files after loading project

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I've loaded a project in Xcode 4 after not looking at it for a while.  Xcode shows its progress bar and indicates in text that the project is loading, and it appears to finish, but then there are no files shown in the hierarchy or flat views.  There is nothing showing in any view (except for one breakpoint in the breakpoints view).

Any ideas?  Xcode gives me zero indication that anything is wrong, it shows me nothing.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I just had the same issue. After a few hours scratching my head and trying all kind of things, I finally found a fix: remove the whole package 'project.xcworkspace' inside the XXXXX.xcodeproj package.

More specifically, when you find the 'XXXXX.xcodeproj' file, right-click it, and select 'Show Package Contents'. This will get you inside the package where you will find the 'package.xcworkspace' file. It is best to do this while the Xcode project is closed.

Maybe that will work for you or for others with the same issue in the future...

Comment: thanks worked like a charm. Any idea what causes that ? I renamed the internal folders a bit, could that have caused it?

Comment: I believe a typical reason could be your VCS messing up with some of the files.

Comment: I need my workspace as I'm using Pods. I just opened project.xcworkspace in Xcode and it worked.

Comment: What worked for me is deleting the MYNAME.xcuserdatad folder

Answer (score 18):

Some of the project views have the "Recently Changed" filter icon.  For me the problem was: i had that enabled in the Project Navigator, so it was only showing the files i recently changed.  It looks like this.  [image]
I'm using Xcode 6.1 though.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. After archiving a project the files would disappear from the project navigator.

It turned out that somehow XCode had added the word "main" to the searchbar below the project navigator so that almost all files where invisible. Quite frustrating.

It might be the same case for you..

Answer (score 5):

For those who make it here, I was opening a older version of a similar iOS project after upgrading to the latest XCode (6.2), and was seeing the symptoms labeled in this question (missing files, folders etc.)

My solution: at the bottom left of the screen, unselecting '**Show only files with source-control status**" which happened to be set on (it's blue when on). The icon looks like a *4-pt star inside a square*.

Comment: They need to reset this flag when an Xcode project is first loaded. I couldn't figure why I wasn't seeing any of my project files and closing and reopening my workspace didn't seem to fix/resolve anything. If they reset the flag when a workspace is first opened, it would have automatically resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

remove the whole package 'project.xcworkspace' inside the XXXXX.xcodeproj package. may cause to any other error so please ignore and trying finally
 You can quit xcode and reload again your project it help you

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to do an alt-tab, on a VM running in TeamViewer in Windows - Click the search bar below, enter delete multiple times and the invisible search term cleared up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Besides the answers above, it could also be that you have already accidentally opened the project in another Xcode window... Close that and reopen everything and it should work.