# My project files are not display in project navigator within xcode after setting up cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode5

When I open .xcworkspace I see "Pods" in the Project Navigator without any files displaying. I know the files are still associated to the project because when I search the project the files display in the Find Navigator. When I build the project, it still builds successfully and my project works fine.  The only problem seem to be that the files are not displaying in the Project Navigator.

This is what my podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
```

Here is a screenshot of what I see in xcode: [image: screenshot]

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: What about if you just open the `Pods` project? I'll probably end up thinking this is an Xcode 5 bug

Comment: It only shows my Pods in that case. http://i.imgur.com/PalmQ28.png

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug to me, you should submit a radar when you can again.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I open the workspace but folders in navigator but they disappear in the actual project folder on my hard drive. They were there, now they're gone. File paths seem ok though. Crazy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996966/xcode-4-shows-no-files-after-loading-project