# Xcode: No Scheme

Tags: xcode

I recently opened project in Xcode is now saying I have `No Scheme`:
[image]

When I try and `Manage Schemes` I am unable to `Autocreate Schemes Now` (a separate post but possibly related) and no Schemes are listed:
[image]

and when I try and add a Scheme I get dialog saying `Target None`.
[image]

What's going on and how do I fix my Xcode project?

Comment: Try to restart your pc..or xcode or both

Comment: Nope, neither worked.

Comment: I upgraded my Mac and ended up with a new version of Xcode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996966/xcode-4-shows-no-files-after-loading-project This did it for me

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Close Xcode and delete the folder `<username>.xcuserdatad` from within `<projectname>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/`. Then restart Xcode, the schemes should re-appear.

**EDIT:**
You may need to delete from `.xcodeproj` file and `.xcworkspace` file

Comment: I've been using a very nice app called Watchdog. It automatically kills xcuserdata on clean or shutdown. You can buy it from the MAS for a couple of bucks.

Comment: I have deleted all three folders under xcuserdata, that worked for me, thanks

Comment: Works even on a [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) based project - where open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xccodeproj`. Removing the `xcuserdatad` leads to a working `.xcworkspace `file as well

Comment: ops, I deleted the .xcodeproj file accidentally, please remove xcuserdata from .xcodeproj, right click on the .xcodeproj and open show packages.

Comment: Switched from npm to yarn and this has helped.

Comment: it worked in me in Xcode 11.4, Cocoapods version 1.9.1. But i had to remove the .xcuserdatad file BEFORE running "pod install" command.

Comment: Worked to me too! Xcode 11.6 - after build failed following accidentally deleting another file too. Huge thanks

Comment: Xcode 12.5. Delete this file`<username>.xcuserdatad` fix my problem. Thanks! I met this when I switch my git commit to an old commit.

Comment: Years later, Version 13.3.1 (13E500a), this is still apparently how it is done.

Answer (score 93):

This worked for me

1. Click on No Scheme
2. Click on Manage Scheme
3. Click on Autocreate Schemes Now

Comment: This should be the correct answer in this thread since it's not a hack and actually works %100 of the time.

Comment: Not working for me. Looks like a valid answer but not 100%.

Comment: Works 100% of the time, except when it doesn't. It doesn't work for me, just for example.

Comment: "I am unable to Autocreate Schemes Now (a separate post but possibly related) and no Schemes are listed:" ...

Comment: This worked for me, but it was not apparent it worked. I had to close XCode and then reopen again.

Answer (score 27):

I think this is happening when you are opening the app.xcworkspace not app.xcodeproj.

Solution:
Install the pod and open the app.xcworkspace again.

Comment: this one did it 

Answer (score 13):

1. Close Xcode ["Force Quit Applications" (cmd+option+escape) to ensure]
2. Remove derived data of app (Xcode 9.4: Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[app directory to delete])
3. Remove .xcworkspace from project directory
4. Also in project directory: .xcodeproj -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> remove .xcworkspace if exist -> xcuserdata -> remove [username].xcuserdatad

It should do the trick. Install pods if needed and open project. Target should be available again.

Comment: Still the best solution for Xcode 12.4 if the .xcworkspace is completely broken. I also suggest doing `pod deintegrate` before doing `pod init` then `pod install`.

Answer (score 8):

Use shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>  or restart.

Comment: much better solution Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For me following worked
Go to your Project Directory and right click on the

> .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace file and select **Show Package Content**

and delete **xcuserdata**.
don't forget to restart the Xcode

- If it do not work and you have CocoPod in your project run the following Command

> Pod install

Comment: The `pod install` line did the job when not even deleting the `xcuserdata` worked.

Answer (score 6):

The top answer fix didn't work for me when running the Xcode 8 beta's. but what did work was unplugging a connected device (iPhone, iPad etc.) and re plugging back in. The schemes would then reappear.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using pods and using the correct workspace what I found to work best is simply open up terminal run pod update restart Xcode and every time it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly,when you are using Cocoapods to Develop iOS projects,you need to open the project with `.xcodeworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj` file.

[image]

**Secondly you can `Show Package Contents` with `.xcworkspace` file,you will find the `contents.xcworkspacedata` file.**

[image]

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:BluetoothColorLamp24G.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:Pods/Pods.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>`

pay attention to this line:

`location = "group:BluetoothColorLamp24G.xcodeproj"`

**The `.xcworkspace` file has reference with the `.xcodeproj` file.**

> If you find there is no file or wrong path about the location,you can link to your `.xcodeproj` file,which works for me.

Development Environment:

`macOS 10.14
Xcode 10.1`

Comment: This is really good answer. it work for me after other options i tried.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I switched to a different Macbook. Running `pod update` fixed everything for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I missed }; in project.pbxproj after resolving conflicts

Comment: This, too, was my problem. I tried running `pod install` and got a huge wall of red. What led me to this solution was when I tried to run `pod deintegrate` I got a message that said the `.pbxproj` was in a merge conflict that wasn't being picked up by my tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try this very simple steps:

- Xcode menu "Product"
- Scheme
- Select another scheme

Answer (score 1):

I will add to this answer::: From @Chris Miles.

`Close Xcode and delete the folder <username>.xcuserdatad from within <projectname>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/. Then restart Xcode, the schemes should re-appear.`

Close Xcode, and everything, about ios development like simulators, then run again you pod install if you are using cocoa pods.

That's works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for people who tried everything in the answers and still did not fix the issue:

Your solution is `git checkout mainline`. Because you probably played around with xcodeproj file and its broken now..

Answer (score 1):

I have Removed pod completely from my project and adding it again.. retrieved my target and all

Answer (score 1):

In my case the cause was renaming the project so I went to Manage Schemas and created the App Schema again (+ button).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the **Major Name Change** off/in your project in the past and after that deleted the Xcode and its data, You will see this issue. When You will clone this project on other device.You will see same issue.
To fix this, go to your pod file, update the target name and install the pods again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. My solution was to look at the project file differences in text mode and I found that `VALID_ARCHS` got reset in two places (`VALID_ARCHS = ""`). Restoring the proper settings for `VALID_ARCHS`, also restored back the Schemes.

Answer (score 0):

This commonly occurs when you `install` a Cocoapod, and try building and running from your `workspace` without first closing your `project`.  If this is the case, `quit Xcode`, then open your app from your workspace and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I rebranched to develop and then the window appeared if I want to resave my project. I must have clicked "close" though. Anyways, I lost my scheme and what helped was rebranching to some other branch, then back to develop and resave how I was supposed to do in the first place