# Open source project has `No Scheme` in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have uploaded an open source project called [SuperCrack!](https://github.com/davechambers/supercrack) to `Github`.  I made it with `Xcode 8.3.3`.  It's quite a large project with lots of `pods`.  I asked a friend to download and build it but he complains that there is `No Scheme`:

[image]

He tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755799/xcode-no-scheme) but said they didn't help.

If anybody could tell me where I went wrong and fix this problem I'd be grateful.

Comment: This project has all you need to be able to clone, open, build and run it. Try  to clone it again from `master` to other directory. This might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.pbxproj` is missing. seems like something went wrong when pushing your project to the server...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when trying to run [this app](https://github.com/RigaDevDay/RigaDevDays-Swift) turns out I just had to run 'pod install'