# Project Scheme is gone Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I open my project today and my project scheme is gone. My File Navigator only has files of the pods I installed. My application files are still there however in the project folder. I attached screenshots of what my problem is so hopefully it makes more sense.

[image: Pod scheme is the only available scheme.]

Pod scheme is the only available scheme

[image]

Project files are still there however they are not in the xcode workspace

[image]

Comment: Did you open the wrong file? What if you drop the whole project folder onto Xcode?

Comment: I am opening my project workspace. I tried adding the project folder but the scheme doesn't change @matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode: No Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755799/xcode-no-scheme)