# Xcode 9 No files in Project Navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9.2

I was working on a project in an xcode .xcworkspace (i have some cocoapods installed) and Xcode suddenly crashed when I attempted to merge a branch into the master branch. When I went to re-open the xcode workspace the files wouldn't load in the project navigator and Xcode says "No Scheme" and won't let me build/run the project.

[image]

I've tried the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755799/xcode-no-scheme) but it didn't solve my issue. Xcode 9 has been horrible so this isn't a huge surprise, seems like I spend more time solving Xcode issues than working on my projects. Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this solved my problem or if it was even this that caused the problem to be resolved but here is what I did...

I was having the issue when I tried to open my project.xcworkspace since this is where I work when I have cocoapods installed in a project. I instead opened the .xcproject, then I discarded all changed in Source Control, I then changed the branch from 'master' to the branch that I was working in when xcode crashed. Next I quit Xcode, then re-opened this time the project.xcworkspace and the problem was resolved.