# I have downloaded my project from a backup in google drive to Xcode but I get nothing

Tags: ios, xcode, backup, xcode7

Here is the problem I have downloaded my project from a backup in google drive, and opened with the .xcworkspace as usual. But I got nothing to run, no targets and no files, what can I do?
[image: The Xcode screen showing nothing!!]

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996966/xcode-4-shows-no-files-after-loading-project

Comment: I deleted the .xcworkspace inside the .xcproject, and it did nothing. :(

Comment: I'm using pods also if it helps

Comment: Make sure you backup deleted files. Do you have 3 files in your package contents?

Comment: yes i have, a .pbx, .xcwork, xcuserdata/

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso Any solution for this ? I have backed up my Xcode project in google drive but now each folder is blank , there is nothing there when I downloaded it.

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani Hi, I think I copied the project to an USB and worked from there, but also check the first comment there are several solution that may work for you. Sorry!