# I have only pods in my scheme in Xcode workspace not other products like my app icon

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, macos-sierra

I had a project in Yosemite using cocoa pods workspace to open it, after I update to Sierra, only pods content are available and my files are not there under xcodeproj file in Xcode inspector

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPQuc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you install pod , you must close current fileProject 
"yourProgramName.xcodeproj" => after install pods will already xcode make file with extensions ".xcworkspace" you must open it .

Comment: yes I know and I have created pods well before these happen, and I was working with it and develop a lot of code with my workspace file, but when I update to OS X Sierra it change to the form you see in the picture, it is kind of disable within .xcworkspace file

Comment: if you open the ".xcworkspace"  try to remove pods and his attached file and 
and reinstall pods ,  because  in your picture seems you open ".xcodeproj"

Comment: and you can make 
1- clear to project " cmd + c " .
2- that delete it from "windows/projects"
3-build project "cmd+b"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996966/xcode-4-shows-no-files-after-loading-project

Comment: how do I delete pods and reinstall again, should I delete it manually ?

Comment: I have seen the post previously but it did not answer my question @Bassam

Comment: delete in manually .
to reinstall it  from terminal 
make " pod init " if you also delete podfile 
pod install

Comment: I've done that but the problem did not solvi had probleme, actually at that time when I copied to another project I had to copy but both of copies changed after chages,  do not know the if from that time

Comment: I delete them manually and I install them again the problem solved but half of my files is not here :(